# read every 25 line of a csv file and pass to list using python

Tags: python, list, csv, reader

I want to read a file and convert every 25 lines of that file into a list, that is, it should have 4 lists with 25 items in each (for 100 lines of a file). I am not being able to get the code for this problem.
The input file looks like this , in actual it has 100 lines:

```
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': 'E1DBEAE3'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.0015'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': '31C6C'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.1129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': '59D40'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.00129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': 'A2A9'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.05129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
```

Also, I want to prepend and append a string to the very first element and the last element of every list respectively, prepend string like :

```
'{"test":[' and append string like: ']}'
```

After prepend and append it should look like for a list size of 3 for example:

```
{"test":[{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': 'E1DBEAE3'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.0015'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': '31C6C'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.1129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': '59D40'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.00129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}
{'PutRequest': {'Item': {'id': {'S': 'A2A9'}, 'value': {'M': {'result': {'N': u'0.05129'}, 'lastupdatedtime': {'S': '2019-06-20'}}}}}}]}
```

I have tried this code:

```
from itertools import islice
list =[]
with open('output_of_json.json', 'r') as infile:
    lines_gen = islice(infile, 25)
    for line in lines_gen:
        list.append(line)
```

Unable to go past the first 25 lines of the file

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: `from itertools import islice`
`list =[]`
`with open(filename', 'r') as infile:`
    `lines_gen = islice(infile, 25)`
    `for line in lines_gen:`
        `list.append(line)`

Not able to go further the first 25 lines @G.Anderson @Mureinik

Comment: Put your code in an edited question, not in comments, please.

Comment: @shalini, `islice(infile, 25)` will iterate over the _first_ 25 lines of the file. It _slices off_ these 25 lines and iterates over them, so there's no wonder you're unable to go past the first 25 lines.

Comment: how do I actually achieve it then? @ForceBru

Comment: That's not a CSV file. It's also not JSON, since it contains single quotes around strings.

Comment: @shalini, you can literally count the lines and start appending to a new list once the count becomes a multiple of 25

Comment: It looks like a Python literal, so you should use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made into a function.  It's logically what you want.  You can use enumerate to clean it up.

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:

    counter = 25
    iteration = -1
    out_dict = {}            

    for i in f.readlines():

        if counter == 25:

            if out_dict[iteration]:

                # append your list
                out_dict[iteration].append('string here')

            counter = 0
            iteration += 1

            # create new instance and pre-pend
            out_dict[iteration] = ['string here']

        out_dict[iteration].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `grouper` function in [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html).

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

from itertools import islice
list =[]
with open('output_of_json.json', 'r') as infile:
    lines_gen = grouper(infile, 25, fillvalue='')
    for line in lines_gen:
        # whatever you want to do
```

Note that if the final block of lines has fewer than 25 lines, that code will fill out the 25 with blank lines.

Comment: You need to call `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the line into a dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm not sure just what the questioner is trying to accomplish. I just showed how to group the lines into chunks of 25 lines. But thanks for your comment--I changed my code slightly to make it more general.

Comment: What about this part of the question: **Also, I want to prepend and append a string to the very first element and the last element of every list respectively, prepend string like**